# datawave - Need to extract data from list and store in string variable which can be used in a SQL IN statement

Tags: sql, list

I have requirement where the input is List

```
{
    "zip_codes": [
        "94587",
        "94544",
        "94566"
    ]
}
```

and I need to use Datawave to store them in a string variable.

```
select * from DB where zipcode in (#zipcode):
```

The zipcode should be comma separated.

SQL statement in actual execution should be

```
select * from  DB where zipcode in (94587,
        94544,
        94566)
```

Answer (score 0):

i was able finally get the output using the below function

```
zipcode: payload.zip_codes joinBy ", "
```

output is zipcode= 94587, 94544, 94566